# Serialization of a class with events

Tags: c#, class, events, serialization, serializable

I have a Class like this:

```
public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
[Serializable]
public class valueDouble
{
    public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;
    public double value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set 
        {
            _value = value;
            if (Changed != null)
            {
                Changed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
    private double _value = 0;
}
```

I also have another Class (StepPulseblaster) which is not serializable and adds an Event Handler

```
valDouble.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(sc_PropertyChanged);
```

When i try to serialize the valueDouble Class, there will be an error:

```
The Type StepPulseblaster is not marked as serializable
```

When i comment the line

```
valDouble.Changed += ...
```

there will be no error any more.

How can i serialize a class which has some events connected?

Comment: Do you want the events to still be there when you deserialize it, or do you want to serialize the data without the events?

Comment: I use the Event to update a GUI, so i need the event after I deserialize it. I have about 1000 duplicates of this Class so I do not really want to delete the event before serialization and create it again.

Comment: Okay, next question: why are you serializing the object? Are you storing it somewhere and reloading it later, or are you making it accessible to a different context (e.g. a different AppDomain or a different process)? You won't be able to serialize the reference to your GUI, but depending on what you need, there may be easy ways to accomplish what you're after.

Comment: I want to save it to disk and be able to restore it later.

Answer (score 33):

You should do:

```
[field: NonSerialized]
public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;
```

As described in the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nonserializedattribute?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> To apply the NonSerializedAttribute class to an event, set the attribute location to **field**.

Comment: Thats interesting, never knew you could do that.

Comment: That link to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163902.aspx) does not seem to go anywhere useful.  Has there been some link rot?

Answer (score 13):

The NonSerialized attribute is only available for fields, so to use it you have to adjust your code to use fields.

Try creating your event like this:

```
[NonSerialized]
private ChangedEventHandler _changed;
public event ChangedEventHandler Changed
{
    add { _changed += value; }
    remove { _changed -= value; }
}
```

Then in the value property use the field, not the property:

```
public double value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set 
    {
        _value = value;
        if (_changed != null)
        {
            _changed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
private double _value = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`[NonSerialized]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) attribute to avoid serialization of the event.

Comment: In VS2010, applying [NonSerialized] to an event gives an error: "Error 2 Attribute 'NonSerialized' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field' declarations."

Answer (score 1):

Either mark StepPulseBlaster as serializable or use the XmlIgnore attribute to prevent Changed from being serialized.